# CAS Tomcat SSLHandshakeException

Tags: tomcat, ssl, cas

I have problems with running CAS using the proxy mode.
However, I don't have any problems with running CAS without the proxy mode.
Here is my development configuration :

- a CAS server with self-signed certificate for ssl created with keytool
- an Apache server with php and phpCAS

Here is the CAS Server log:

```
2012-03-20 09:25:20,080 INFO [org.jasig.cas.util.AutowiringSchedulerFactoryBean] - Shutting down Quartz Scheduler
2012-03-20 09:25:54,194 INFO [org.jasig.cas.services.DefaultServicesManagerImpl] - Loaded 4 services.
2012-03-20 09:25:54,304 WARN [org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler] - org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler is only to be used in a testing environment.  NEVER enable this in a production environment.
2012-03-20 09:25:55,074 INFO [org.jasig.cas.util.AutowiringSchedulerFactoryBean] - Starting Quartz Scheduler now
2012-03-20 09:26:13,865 INFO [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.DefaultTicketRegistryCleaner] - Beginning ticket cleanup.
2012-03-20 09:26:13,865 INFO [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.DefaultTicketRegistryCleaner] - 0 tickets found to be removed.
2012-03-20 09:26:13,866 INFO [org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.support.DefaultTicketRegistryCleaner] - Finished ticket cleanup.
2012-03-20 09:26:15,490 INFO [org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction] - Setting path for cookies to: /cas/
2012-03-20 09:26:15,490 INFO [org.jasig.cas.web.flow.InitialFlowSetupAction] - Setting path for cookies to: /cas/
2012-03-20 09:26:51,732 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: audit:unknown
WHAT: https://myurl/mypage.php
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_NOT_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Tue Mar 20 09:26:51 EDT 2012
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 192.168.56.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 192.168.56.21
=============================================================


2012-03-20 09:26:54,661 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - AuthenticationHandler: org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler successfully authenticated the user which provided the following credentials: [username: uday]
2012-03-20 09:26:54,663 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - Resolved principal uday
2012-03-20 09:26:54,663 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - Principal found: uday
2012-03-20 09:26:54,666 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: [username: uday]
WHAT: supplied credentials: [username: uday]
ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Tue Mar 20 09:26:54 EDT 2012
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 192.168.56.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 192.168.56.21
=============================================================


2012-03-20 09:26:54,671 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: [username: uday]
WHAT: TGT-1-k6WfKXIbw0oA9xOHeDnDuF9lT1Jxa6Gxcf2KLrSMpPewhR5oL3-cas
ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Tue Mar 20 09:26:54 EDT 2012
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 192.168.56.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 192.168.56.21
=============================================================


2012-03-20 09:26:54,672 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: audit:unknown
WHAT: TGT-1-e7IpmWoXBe0DZ1mriUtNnuyMA7Rd6zyiIueIXNH0DBY04NKVUn-cas
ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_DESTROYED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Tue Mar 20 09:26:54 EDT 2012
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 192.168.56.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 192.168.56.21
=============================================================


2012-03-20 09:26:54,674 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - Granted service ticket [ST-1-51JadzMUuXlQUBAOzNIB-cas] for service [https://myurl/mypage.php] for user [uday]
2012-03-20 09:26:54,675 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: uday
WHAT: ST-1-51JadzMUuXlQUBAOzNIB-cas for https://myurl/mypage.php
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Tue Mar 20 09:26:54 EDT 2012
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 192.168.56.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 192.168.56.21
=============================================================


2012-03-20 09:26:54,861 ERROR [org.jasig.cas.util.HttpClient] - sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1697)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:258)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:252)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1165)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:610)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:546)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:945)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1190)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1217)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1201)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:423)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.followRedirect(HttpURLConnection.java:2030)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:397)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
    at org.jasig.cas.util.HttpClient.isValidEndPoint_aroundBody4(HttpClient.java:111)
    at org.jasig.cas.util.HttpClient.isValidEndPoint_aroundBody5$advice(HttpClient.java:44)
    at org.jasig.cas.util.HttpClient.isValidEndPoint(HttpClient.java:1)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler.authenticate_aroundBody0(HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler.java:59)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler.authenticate_aroundBody1$advice(HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler.java:44)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler.authenticate(HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler.java:1)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl.authenticateAndObtainPrincipal(AuthenticationManagerImpl.java:84)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate_aroundBody0(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:41)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate_aroundBody1$advice(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:44)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
    at com.github.inspektr.audit.AuditTrailManagementAspect.handleAuditTrail(AuditTrailManagementAspect.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy17.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.delegateTicketGrantingTicket_aroundBody6(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:272)
    at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.delegateTicketGrantingTicket_aroundBody7$advice(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:44)
    at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.delegateTicketGrantingTicket(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    [...]
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service_aroundBody2(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:115)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service_aroundBody3$advice(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:44)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:1)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.github.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:205)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:235)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:147)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:230)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:270)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1144)
    ... 113 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:197)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:255)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:297)
    ... 119 more
2012-03-20 09:26:54,873 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - AuthenticationHandler: org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler failed to authenticate the user which provided the following credentials: [callbackUrl: https://myurl/mypage.php]
2012-03-20 09:26:54,876 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: [callbackUrl: https://myurl/mypage.php]
WHAT: supplied credentials: [callbackUrl: https://myurl/mypage.php]
ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Tue Mar 20 09:26:54 EDT 2012
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 192.168.56.20
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 192.168.56.21
=============================================================


2012-03-20 09:26:54,879 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: uday
WHAT: error.authentication.credentials.bad
ACTION: PROXY_GRANTING_TICKET_NOT_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Tue Mar 20 09:26:54 EDT 2012
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 192.168.56.20
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 192.168.56.21
=============================================================


2012-03-20 09:26:54,879 ERROR [org.jasig.cas.web.ServiceValidateController] - TicketException generating ticket for: [callbackUrl: https://myurl/mypage.php]
org.jasig.cas.ticket.TicketCreationException: error.authentication.credentials.bad
    at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.delegateTicketGrantingTicket_aroundBody6(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:300)
    at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.delegateTicketGrantingTicket_aroundBody7$advice(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:44)
    at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.delegateTicketGrantingTicket(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
    at org.perf4j.aop.AbstractTimingAspect$1.proceed(AbstractTimingAspect.java:47)
    at org.perf4j.aop.AgnosticTimingAspect.runProfiledMethod(AgnosticTimingAspect.java:53)
    at org.perf4j.aop.AbstractTimingAspect.doPerfLogging(AbstractTimingAspect.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
    at com.github.inspektr.audit.AuditTrailManagementAspect.handleAuditTrail(AuditTrailManagementAspect.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy18.delegateTicketGrantingTicket(Unknown Source)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.ServiceValidateController.handleRequestInternal(ServiceValidateController.java:125)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service_aroundBody2(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:115)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service_aroundBody3$advice(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:44)
    at org.jasig.cas.web.init.SafeDispatcherServlet.service(SafeDispatcherServlet.java:1)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.github.inspektr.common.web.ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(ClientInfoThreadLocalFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: error.authentication.credentials.bad
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.BadCredentialsAuthenticationException.<clinit>(BadCredentialsAuthenticationException.java:25)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl.authenticateAndObtainPrincipal(AuthenticationManagerImpl.java:112)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate_aroundBody0(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:41)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate_aroundBody1$advice(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:44)
    at org.jasig.cas.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:1)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:80)
    at com.github.inspektr.audit.AuditTrailManagementAspect.handleAuditTrail(AuditTrailManagementAspect.java:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:65)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:161)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy17.authenticate(Unknown Source)
    at org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.delegateTicketGrantingTicket_aroundBody6(CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl.java:272)
    ... 68 more
2012-03-20 09:26:54,890 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: audit:unknown
WHAT: ST-1-51JadzMUuXlQUBAOzNIB-cas
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_VALIDATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Tue Mar 20 09:26:54 EDT 2012
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 192.168.56.20
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 192.168.56.21
=============================================================
```

I looked in the [troubleshooting](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/SSL+Troubleshooting+and+Reference+Guide) and found my error but I am unable to resolve it.

I imported the self-signed certificate of https://myurl/ in the tomcat keystore and restarted tomcat but I am still getting this error.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:**
Here is the content of my keystore and truststore (listed by keytool -v -list -keystore /path/to/keystore):

```
Type Keystore : JKS
Fournisseur Keystore : SUN

Votre Keystore contient 3 entrée(s)

Nom d'alias : tomcat
Date de création : 2012-03-08
Type dentrée : {0}
Longueur de chaîne du certificat : 1
Certificat[1]:
Propriétaire : CN=cas, OU=Company, O=Company, L=City, ST=Province, C=PR
Émetteur : CN=cas, OU=Company, O=Company, L=City, ST=Province, C=PR
Numéro de série : 4f58d082
Valide du : Thu Mar 08 10:30:10 EST 2012 au : Wed Jun 06 11:30:10 EDT 2012
Empreintes du certificat :
     MD5 :  F7:8D:3D:A0:24:31:B8:75:5E:AB:56:2B:80:66:1E:D8
     SHA1 : 74:44:47:AD:CE:0A:00:DB:F4:F0:5B:0C:48:38:37:4A:A3:2F:E5:C2
     Nom de lalgorithme de signature : {7}
     Version : {8}


*******************************************
*******************************************
Nom d'alias : myurl
Date de création : 2012-03-21
Type d'entrée : trustedCertEntry

Propriétaire : CN=myurl
Émetteur : CN=myurl
Numéro de série : fc657300d50bdecd
Valide du : Wed Mar 21 13:09:15 EDT 2012 au : Sat Mar 19 13:09:15 EDT 2022
Empreintes du certificat :
     MD5 :  9C:0B:3F:F8:AE:02:AD:63:D8:17:6D:60:84:90:69:AE
     SHA1 : 7B:FF:1C:14:D7:36:36:5A:B0:A3:89:4E:F9:C7:8C:B0:75:B8:62:24
     Nom de lalgorithme de signature : {7}
     Version : {8}


*******************************************
*******************************************
```

**Edit 2:**
Here is my tomcat connector:

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keyAlias="tomcat"
           keystoreFile="/home/keystore"
           keystorePass="changeit" truststoreFile="/home/keystore" 
           truststorePass="changeit"/>
```

/home/keystore is the path to the above file.
Do I need to provide a trust alias?
If yes, what is the attribute name for that alias?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved my problem by using free ssl certificates from [StartSSL](http://www.startssl.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the self-signed certificate into your truststore. Have you done that ?

Comment: I imported the self-signed certificate of apache (https://myurl/) in the tomcat keystore. Is that what you mean? If no, which certificate should I import (the tomcat (https://cas/) one or the apache (https://myurl/) one)? And where should I import it? Thanks.

Comment: There are two keystores - identity and trust. You mentioned that you create a "self-signed certificate for ssl" ; this is the identity keystore. You need to take this key and import it into your trust store.

Comment: I've done that by I still get the same error. I edited my answer to show you the content of my keystore and trustore. May you tell me what is wrong please?

Comment: I cannot tell which keystore that is but will take your word for it. If you are sure about that, you need to verify that tomcat is pointing to the correct keystores. Please verify.

Comment: It seems to be ok. To be sure, I edited my post to show you the tomcat connector.

Comment: Create a separate store, call it truststore, import the cert into it and make sure you import it as a trusted cert.

Comment: I did that, updated the tomcat connector and restarted tomcat without success: I get the same error. Is there a way to get additionnal information in the log file?

Comment: To clarify - if you access tomcat via Apache httpd it fails ; but it works fine using standalone tomcat ? Can you confirm that you have imported the above cert into Apache as well ?